# How can I make aggregator to output N documents instead of one document with N rows?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.entities.aggregate([
    {$limit: 80000},
    {$unwind: '$documents'},
    {$unwind: '$documents.subjects'},
    {$unwind: '$documents.subjects.journal_entries'},
    {$match: {'documents.subjects.journal_entries.date':{$gte: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"), $lte: ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00.0Z")}}},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id", "total": {$sum: '$documents.subjects.journal_entries.amount'}}},
]);
```

Here is my aggregator query. It outputs one document with field results and the results field have rows. Each row is basically a document.

I want each row to be it is own document. I will be querying a large number of rows and this behavior of Mongo breaks my querying because it exceeds the maximum size of the document (16Mb).

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Current output:

```
{
    results: [
        {_id: ..., total: ...},
        {_id: ..., total: ...}
        {_id: ..., total: ...}
        {_id: ..., total: ...}
        {_id: ..., total: ...}
        {_id: ..., total: ...}
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{_id: ..., total: ...};
{_id: ..., total: ...};
{_id: ..., total: ...};
{_id: ..., total: ...};
{_id: ..., total: ...};
{_id: ..., total: ...};
```

*Semicolon is a separator for a new document*

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Please show you documents with expected output?

Comment: Updated my answer to show the expected and the actual output

Comment: You appear to have an older MongoDB version installed with meteor or are connecting to an older instance (2.4.x). You need at least a MongoDB 2.6.x instance to return results as a cursor rather than a single BSON Document.

Comment: The JS code that I am showing is from Mongo console itself. Not meteor. Mongo version installed is 3.0.6; I have also tested it with PHP 5.6 latest driver and had no luck. I am going to investigate more if this is not a problem with my aggregators code.